# Wrong time on linux

Tags: internet, sync, time

I have two systems - Ubuntu and Windows, a each of them shows different time. I set "auto internet sync" on both, and it's not working properly. There is a 2h difference for some reason. So when I set on ubuntu 10:48 after restart I will get 8:48 on Windows. When I set on Windows 10:48, after restart on ubuntu I will get 12:48.
Anyone had something similar ? Why auto internet sync is not working ?

Comment: Are both systems configured to use the same timezone? It sounds like they are on different ones.

Comment: Check [UbuntuTime](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime) help page